# Create global modal that calls different fuctions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-context

For instance, I have a modal with a dialog to confirm saving changes. This modal is used in multiple components but it has to call different functions depending on the component. The function it calls exists inside a component.

It would be nice to create a reusable global modal component (with Redux or React Context) that can accept different functions depending on the screen where it's used

I know that you can't store non-serializable values in reducers, so I'm wondering is there an elegant way to handle such cases without having to import the modal inside each separate component?

Comment: Have you tried sending the relevant function as a prop to the component?

Comment: The thing is that I wanted to keep the Modal component at the root level of my app but I can't feed the function to the modal component because it cannot be stored in a reducer since function are non-serializable. I want to avoid importing the Modal and controlling its state (open/close) inside each of the components

Comment: " I want to avoid importing the Modal and controlling its state (open/close) inside each of the components". Then create another component that uses the modal and have that component control the state and do the function callback. That component can then be imported where you need it.

Comment: There has come [`react-modal-global`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal-global), that may fit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `ModalProvider` and place it after your `ReduxProvider` or `ContextProvider` to **consume** the state(store) values and actions. Let's demonstrate it with some example codes, I'm referring to use `Redux` but you can use `ContextApi` as same.

First, define a general/global modal provider

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const ModalProvider = ({children}) => {
  const modal = useSelector(state => state.modal)

  return(
    <ModalComponent isVisible={modal.isVisible} title={modal.title} >
      {children}
    </ModalComponent>
  )
}

export default ModalProvider;
```

**Note:** `ModalComponent` is a sample modal component that gives the title, modal status, and other options you may need in your application.

Now, time to use `ModalProvider` in the root component:

```
import ReduxProvider from 'path/to/your/redux/provider';
import ModalProvider from 'path/to/your/modal/proivder';

const App = () => (
  <ReduxProvider store={store} >
    // put the ModalProvider after the ReduxProvider
    <ModalProvider>
      // your other providers, toasts, routes ...
    </ModalProvider>
  </ReduxProvider>
)

export default App;
```

**Note:** `ModalProvider` must be placed after the `ReduxProvider` to consume the state object.

complete the redux implementation by defining proper `reducer` and `actions`:

the sample actions:

```
const OPEN_MODAL = "OPEN_MODAL";
const CLOSE_MODAL = "CLOSE_MODAL";

const openModal = (modalData) => ({type: OEPN_MODAL, payload: modalData})
const closeModal = () => ({type: CLOSE_MODAL})
```

and, the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  isVisible: false,
  title: "",
  description: "",
  // and so on for the rest of details depend on your application
}

const modalReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case OPEN_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isVisible: true,
        title: action.payload.title,
        description: action.payload.description
      }
    case CLOSE_MODAL: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isVisible: false,
        title: "",
        description: ""
      }
     default: 
       return state;
    }
  }
}
```

##### Important Note:

you may need a `toggleModal` action or other actions to control your modal behavior, so implement them with your desire.

Finally, use `dispatch` method to dispatching the proper actions in your components/pages.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

const SampleComponet = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleOpenInfoModal = (title, description) => {
     dispatch(openModal({title, description}))
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleOpenInfoModal("the info modal", "some description to display in the modal body")}>
         More Info
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

##### UPDATE

To passing custom methods and functions on `ModalCompnent` you can use a tricky way:

inside of `ModalComponent`:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

handleOnclose = () => {
  dispatch({tye: onCloseAction})
}

hadnleOpenClose = () => {
  dispatch({type: onOpenAction})
}

return(
  <div>
    <p>{title}</p>
    <p>{description}</p>
    <button onClick={handleOnClose}> CLOSE </button>
    <button onClick={handleOnOpen}> OPEN </button>
    // ... 
)
```

**Explanation:**
`onCloseAction` and `onOpenAction` are the same as the title and description, they are strings, but they got the **action name** and dispatch it.
Since you can't sterilize a function in the store, you can save the action name which is a string to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
What if I want to have the same exact modal performing different action in different places. The ideal solution would be to dispatch an object containing a function like this ```const handleOpenInfoModal = (title, description, action) => {
     dispatch(openModal({title, description, action }))
  }```
Where ```action``` is a random function
But unfortunately, that's not something you can do with Redux or Context

Comment: It's my pleasure @AleksandrFomin .

Comment: why didn't you define your actions in the action section then export and use them inside of your component? 
passing a function into the redux store (which is an object) useless since the proper way is to using the dispatch method to dispatch proper action. you can also define a thousand actions for your modal component with different effects in your reducer @AleksandrFomin

Comment: I guess you need to pass some function to the modal to be placed inside of your modal and do some actions with the user's interaction with the modal itself. is this correct? @AleksandrFomin

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to passing actions with your dispatcher function. it can be implemented just by using the "modal component" in the other pages/components. but you can define some functionality in the modal component and use some property to conditonllay use them @AleksandrFomin

Comment: I've updated my answer right now, please take a look and give me feedback @AleksandrFomin

Comment: if the updated section meets your goals, I can edit my post to remove unnecessary parts like defining "ModalProvider" and so on ... @AleksandrFomin

Comment: I'm afraid it's not going to work for me since the functions that are supposed to be run by the modal require parameters that are calculated within the component. Also, the functions run API requests with ReduxToolkit Query lib, so I'm not dispatching anything to the store I just run the function and receive the response directly inside my component. I hope that makes sense to you